# Meaning of output messages when doing a git clone

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I was doing a git clone and I received some messages on the terminal which are:

```
Cloning into 'mychain'...
remote: Counting objects: 251877, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (115770/115770), done.
Receiving objects:  51% (129595/251877), 754.84 MiB | 155.00 KiB/s
```

I know the meaning of:

1. First line: It means it is creating .git in a directory called
   'mychain'
2. Second line: It means the number of objects that is present in the remote is 251877
3. Third line: It means that the objects are compressed into 115770 compressed objects.
4. Fourth line: I am not sure about this part: `754.84 MiB | 155.00 KiB/s`

Can someone tell me something about the fourth part? Also, please correct me if I was wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`754.84 MiB` is the downloaded size of your repository on the local disk. Note that it is the current size that is 51% of the total size of the actual repository.
`155.00 KiB/s` is the current download speed.

Comment: Yeah! You are right, I guess. I just checked the size of the folder 'mychain' and it is equal to whatever MiB I have now showing on my terminal. Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering about the meaning of "i" in "MiB", and found this article informative: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22102/meaning-of-i-in-mib

Answer (score 1):

When you're cloning a git repository, you're getting the full history of the specified git repo. The last line is telling you that you already downloaded 754.84 MiB of the repo. And the 155.00 KiB/s is your downloading rate.